# How to extract t[i,i,:] using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example:

```
t = tf.constant(np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]))
# I want to extract h = [[1,2],[7,8]]
```

How to use tensorflow to do this? Thank you!

Comment: How are these slices defined? What is [i,i,n]?

Comment: i is a loop variable. h = [t[0,0,:], t[1,1,:]]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.gather_nd()`. It gathers slices from the last dimension given some indices. You can read more on that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd).

```
import tensorflow as tf


t = tf.constant(np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]))
t_res = tf.gather_nd(t, [(0,0),(1,1)])
sess = tf.Session()
h = sess.run(t_res) # >>>[[1,2],[7,8]]
```